# Do I need a cache plugin if I am using service workers or a managed Wordpress hosting?

Tags: wordpress

I am developing my WordPress site and planning to convert it in a PWA and I know there is something called "Service Workers" that deal with the cache.

If I will convert my site to a PWA or I have a managed Wordpress hosting do I need cache plugin?

Comment: Who do you host with?

Comment: planning to use WPEngine

Comment: Nice, I've only had good experiences with them. They use their own caching functionality. Take a read over this: https://wpengine.co.uk/support/disallowed-plugins/ Also, Cloudflare is a good addition with WP Engine: https://wpengine.co.uk/support/cloudflare-best-practices/